# BooleanExpression if exists querydsl

Tags: querydsl

How I can check is true/false to go in different scenarios?

```
BooleanExpression exists = JPAexpression.selectOne().from(qUserJob)
.where(qUserJob.user.eq(user),
qUserJob.job.eq(job)).exists();
```

Is possible to convert BooleanExpression to boolean to able use it in if statement?

Like this:

```
if(exists){
dosomeLogic();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`exists()` is used for rendering `EXISTS (subquery)` expressions. If you want a boolean result, you should just let the outermost query return any result and process the result accordingly, for example:

```java
boolean exists = query()
    .select(qUserJob)
    .from(qUserJob)
    .where(qUserJob.user.eq(user), qUserJob.job.eq(job))
    .fetchCount() > 0;
```